# Python : How to make accuracy and loss graph from my image dataset with my own h5 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

just like my question above. I want to plot a trainig graph and validation graph. But all I found are import from other online dataset(which I don't want since I have my own, already tried to edit and make it for my own, but failed, miserably). I don't know how to make it, I have my trained models which is h5 files, but I don't know how to plotting the graph with this. Did I done it wrong? Or I made a mistake somewhere?

Here's the code I use and modify, but failed.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a new generator
imagegen = ImageDataGenerator()

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
)

# load val data
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"dataset path",
                                                  class_mode="categorical",
                                                  shuffle=False,
                                                  batch_size=3,
                                                  target_size=(200, 200))

history = keras.models.load_model(r"dataset path.h5")

# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

and got this error.

```
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Validation Graph\main.py", line 27, in <module>
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This is one of many that failed, but I'm tried of fixing this by myself. Please tell me what I did wrong, and how I make it right with my dataset still include in this.

Comment: Sorry if my englist is bad, I'm not english native.

Comment: `.fit()` method of `keras.Sequential` class returns `History` object. You can only plot it

Comment: Can you show me? I'm done doing this now, I'm so tried of this.

Comment: I need a break form this for time being. Need to rest my brain. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

below is a function that will plot training and validation losses and accuracy

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
def tr_plot(tr_data, start_epoch):
    #Plot the training and validation data
    tacc=tr_data.history['accuracy']
    tloss=tr_data.history['loss']
    vacc=tr_data.history['val_accuracy']
    vloss=tr_data.history['val_loss']
    Epoch_count=len(tacc)+ start_epoch
    Epochs=[]
    for i in range (start_epoch ,Epoch_count):
        Epochs.append(i+1)   
    index_loss=np.argmin(vloss)#  this is the epoch with the lowest validation loss
    val_lowest=vloss[index_loss]
    index_acc=np.argmax(vacc)
    acc_highest=vacc[index_acc]
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    sc_label='best epoch= '+ str(index_loss+1 +start_epoch)
    vc_label='best epoch= '+ str(index_acc + 1+ start_epoch)
    fig,axes=plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(25,10))
    axes[0].plot(Epochs,tloss, 'r', label='Training loss')
    axes[0].plot(Epochs,vloss,'g',label='Validation loss' )
    axes[0].scatter(index_loss+1 +start_epoch,val_lowest, s=150, c= 'blue', label=sc_label)
    axes[0].scatter(Epochs, tloss, s=100, c='red')    
    axes[0].set_title('Training and Validation Loss')
    axes[0].set_xlabel('Epochs', fontsize=18)
    axes[0].set_ylabel('Loss', fontsize=18)
    axes[0].legend()
    axes[1].plot (Epochs,tacc,'r',label= 'Training Accuracy')
    axes[1].scatter(Epochs, tacc, s=100, c='red')
    axes[1].plot (Epochs,vacc,'g',label= 'Validation Accuracy')
    axes[1].scatter(index_acc+1 +start_epoch,acc_highest, s=150, c= 'blue', label=vc_label)
    axes[1].set_title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
    axes[1].set_xlabel('Epochs', fontsize=18)
    axes[1].set_ylabel('Accuracy', fontsize=18)
    axes[1].legend()
    plt.tight_layout    
    plt.show()
    return index_loss
```

to use this first train your model using model.fit but first you need to create a training generator and a validation generator

```
gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255,rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=0.2,
                         height_shift_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
train_gen=gen.flow_from_directory(r"dataset path", target_size=(200,200),
                                  batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=123,
                                  class_mode='categorical, subset='training')
valid_gen=gen.flow_from_directory(r"dataset path", target_size=(200,200),
                                  batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=123,
                                  class_mode='categorical, subset='validation')
```

next train your model. I assume you created a model

```
epochs=10
history=model.fit(x=train_gen,  , epochs=epochs, verbose=1, 
                  validation_data=valid_gen,  shuffle=False,  initial_epoch=0)
```

then to plot the results

```
loss_index=tr_plot(history,0)
```

Comment: Got a problem, valid_gen got 0 image. I'm not misplace the path and there's a lot of image but why it appear 0?